# Identify this set: bags with grey, blue and red

Tags: set-identification, instructions

I am in need of identifying instructions for numbered Lego bags that were handed down from a friend, so my son can start building. They are identified as 4, 5 and 6. I’ve read that the numbers on the bags aren’t helpful so I’ve attached pictures with some identifying pieces to hopefully help! I assume they are from the same kit.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Noelle and welcome to Bricks.SE! The numbers on the bag don't tell much, there are many sets with at least 6 bags. The pictures are a great idea though, but they seem to have gotten lost somewhere. Can you please edit your question to add them again?

Answer (score 8):

Based solely on [*Minifigure Armor Breastplate with Pentagonal Cutout on Front and 2 Studs on Back with Trans-Neon Orange Shoulder Pads Pattern*](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=24097pb01) (wow that's a mouthful)...

[image: shoulder pads]

...which [appears in just 12 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=24097pb01&in=S), the set can be identified as [70317-1 The Fortrex](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70317-1):

[image: The Fortrex]

Now that you're armed with the set number `70317`, it's trivial to [search for its instructions](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/search?q=70317) in the LEGO website.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! You made a little Lego builder very happy!